# Solve the recursion

Tags: recursion

I am trying to solve the recursion $T (k) = T (k/5) + k^2$ and I can't figure out after the following step.
    $$\begin{align}T(k) &= T (k/5) + k^2\\    
&= (T(k/25) + k^2/25) + k^2\\
&= (T(k/625) + k^2/625) + k^2/25 + k^2\\
&= T(1) + … + k^2/625 + k^2/25 + k^2\\
&= k^2+ k^2/25+ k^2/625 +…+ T(1)
\end{align}$$

Comment: this is a question that falls under the general category of [functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_equation) which, in general means the "unknown" you're solving for represents a function. Typically, the function at a certain value will be related to the same function at other values and functions that satisfy this relation are said to be "solutions". Here is wolframs solution https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%28x%29-y%28x%2F5%29%3Dx%5E2. In general, there is no clear cut method to solving these types of equations and in fact numerical analysis may be necessary.

Comment: Where did the $T(1)$ come from? As you use the recursive equation to expand, doesn’t that term approach $T(0)$, assuming the function is continuous, or else not necessarily approach anything, in which case why call it $T(1)$?

Comment: $1+1/25+1/625+\cdots=25/24$, so you might guess $T(k)=25k^2/24 + C$.

Answer (score 1):

You might just guess that $T(n)$ is of the form $an^2$, then
$$T(k)=ak^2=T(\frac k5)+k^2=a(\frac k5)^2+k^2\\
ak^2=\frac a{25}k^2+k^2\\
a=\frac a{25}+1\\
a=\frac {25}{24}\\
T(k)=\frac {25}{24}k^2$$

Comment: If $T(k)$ is continuous at $k=0$, then isn’t the general solution $\frac{25k^2}{24} +T(0)$, which can be determined straight from the geometric series?